# Relationship Map - Financial Service Cloud Custom Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, experience-cloud, financial-services-cloud

So I have access to the Relationship Map within my org as a user, however, I am trying to pull it into an experience site.
I have access to the other custom and standard components within the FSC Relationship page (Related contacts, Related Accounts, Relationship Groups) as well as the ARC Graph.
However, I cannot find it available in the list of available components within the experience site.
Is there perhaps something I am missing?
If this is a custom component that needs to be written from scratch, is there any insight in regards to where to start?

[image]